# ClojureScript Dropdown Menu

Tags: html, clojurescript

I have a html page that contains a navigation bar at the top of the screen. In the navigation bar, I have a search box and what I want it to do is, you type in this box, hit enter and the results are displayed as a dropdown menu

```
<li><input type="text" id="search-bar" placeholder="Search"></li>
```

This is the html search input box. I have given it an id `search-bar` to eventually create the dropdown menu in ClojureScript

```
(when-let [section (. js/document (getElementById "search-bar"))]
                (r/render-component [search-bar-component] section))
```

Currently I have a search-form that looks like the following

```
(defn search-form
  []
  [:div
   [:p "What are you searching for? "
    [:input
     {:type :text
      :name :search
      :on-change #(do
                    (swap! fields assoc :search (-> % .-target .-value))
                    (search-index (:search @fields)))
      :value (:search @fields)}]]
   [:p (create-links @search-results)]])

(defn- search-component
  []
  [search-form])
```

This is my `search-component`.

What I want to happen is when you type in the input box on the navbar (say "hello", it calls `search-index` from the search-form with the parameter being the value you type in ("hello") and then returns the results as a dropdown menu below.

`search-form` works right now as a form on a html page, where you input some text into a form and then the results are displayed below. I want to change it to be on the navbar instead of as a separate page, where the input form is on the navbar and the results are displayed below

How would I have to change my search-form in order to do this?

I think I can do something along the lines of this

```
(defn search-bar-form
      []
      [:div
       [:input
        {:type :text
         :name :search
         :on-change #(do
                       (swap! fields assoc :search (-> % .-target .-value))
                       (search-index (:search @fields)))
         :value (:search @fields)}]
       [:p (create-links @search-results)]])

(defn- search-bar-component
       []
       [search-form])
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[re-com](https://github.com/Day8/re-com) provides a [typeahead component](http://re-demo.s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/#/typeahead). It looks like you're using reagent, so you could just use that, otherwise you can use it as inspiration.